# Remove unnecessary usings with dotnet format

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

We have [dotnet format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format) to apply formatting to csproj or even sln file for the entire solution.

I can do that [using Visual Studio 2022 Quick Action Light Bulb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2022) feature.

[image: Visaul Studio Quick Action Light Bulb feature in Visual Studio 2022]

So is there a way I can do that using dotnet format command configured using [editorconfig settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: I don't believe so, but you can include that action as part of your Code Cleanup Profile 1 or Profile 2.

Answer (score 16):

If you include the following in your .editorconfig file, it is now supported:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0005.severity = error
```

I tried to find anywhere in the changelog where this is referenced, without success.

However do be aware: that you might need to update your IDE, as Rider version 2021 doesn't know that tasks are standard now.

Comment: This worked for me but it also removed many required usings from the test project for namespaces in the library project in my solution.

Comment: Sounds weird - which imports and how was this the case? if you provide a minimum reproducable example, I'll gladly try to help.